# How to find Typography component wrapped in MockedProvider when testing with enzyme

Tags: reactjs, testing, enzyme, react-apollo, react-testing-library

New to testing, trying to figure out how to test whether the parent component renders the correct child components. Say this is the main component:

```
export const ParentComponent = () => {
 const {loading, error, data} = useQuery(someQuery);
 //some work with the data
 return (
 <>
   <div>
     <Component1></Component1>
     <Component2></Component2>
   </div>
   <div>
     <div>
       <Typography> Some text </Typography>
     </div>
   </div>
 </>
}
```

I want to find the `Typography` component, this is what I had in mind, but it's not finding it:

```
  it("should render a Typography component", async () => {
    const wrapper = createMount(
      <MockedProvider mocks={mocks} addTypename={false}>
        <ParentComponent />
      </MockedProvider>
    );
    wrapper.update();
    let parentComponent = wrapper.find(ParentComponent);
    expect(parentComponent).toHaveLength(1); // passes
    expect(parentComponent.childAt(1).find(Typography)).toHaveLength(1); //doesn't pass
})
```

I also replicated the following: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/development-testing/testing/#testing-final-state
Instead of finding the `'p'` tag, I want to find the `Typography` component

Answer (score 0):

`material-ui` not always names its html elements the same as react components. When it comes to testing, I, personally, just set an `id` on a component and use it to find my component.